# Image processing: Average grayscale images

Tags: r

I would like to average two grayscale images (both png files of the same size) using R.

Consider the images below as an example:

`img1.png`

[image]

`img2.png`

[image]

`img3.png`

[image]

The average of `img1.png` and `img2.png` should result in something like `img3.png`. I've looked into the [magick](https://github.com/ropensci/magick) and [imager](https://dahtah.github.io/imager/imager.html) packages without success.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Surely there are multiple solutions to this problem. Here's one that shows clearly what's happening and allows for more flexibility.

Let's load your two example pictures.

```
library(png)
img1 <- readPNG("owzUE.png")
img2 <- readPNG("HMka0.png")
```

It happens that they are not of identical size:

```
dim(img1)
# [1] 145 190   4
dim(img2)
# [1] 144 191   4
```

So, let's make the size the same with

```
img1 <- img1[1:144, 1:190, 1:4]
img2 <- img2[1:144, 1:190, 1:4]
```

Each image consists of four matrices, the first three corresponding to the RGB channels and the last one to alpha. Let's define the resulting image by

```
img3 <- img1 * 0
```

which nicely gives an array of the same size as `img1` and `img2`.

A closely related concept is [alpha blending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) but the formulas are not exactly what you need; there the relationship between images doesn't seem to be symmetric. What we may do is to consider a weighted average for each RGB channel, where weights correspond to the corresponding alphas:

```
for(d in 1:3)
  img3[, , d] <- (img1[, , d] * img1[, , 4]  + img2[, , d] * img2[, , 4] ) / (img1[, , 4] + img2[, , 4])
```

Since in some cases both alphas are 0, we fix those cases with

```
img3[is.nan(img3)] <- 0
```

Lastly, we set alpha value to a larger one of the two images with

```
img3[, , 4] <- pmax(img1[, , 4], img2[, , 4])
```

and save the result

```
writePNG(img3, "img3.png")
```

[image]

So, this method also applies to color images and allows one to experiment with the formula by varying weights, etc.